# IEEEtran \title{ * } does not show

Tags: ieeetran

I'm practicing LaTeX with `IEEEtran.cls`. I'm am slowly filling in the information, but I am getting stuck from the beginning.

```
\documentclass[12pt, journal, compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\title{ This is my practice document}
\author{Yui}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract content goes here.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

From the above simple `.tex` file, after compilation in the PDF, I can see the Abstract content. However, I don't see either title or author.

Comment: You have to include the command `\maketitle` to actually show the title and the authors.  `\title` and `\author` just store the content.

Comment: @Guido Maybe you should write an answer (just to close the thread)

Answer (score 3):

To output the title and author of a document using `IEEEtran.cls` (and in almost all LaTeX classes) is produced by the `\maketitle` command.